# Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to . Unit test windows phone

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I Have two projects in my solution. One is my application and the other one is the UnitTest project.

Here is the code of my class UnitTest

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void initialize()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void cleanup()
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I have this output:

------ Run test started ------
Deploying application for project: TestApp1...
Connecting to phone...
Deployment for project TestApp1 succeeded. Time taken: 2 sec
Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to .
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:01:04,8949798) ==========

The default processor archittecture is x86.
I did not find any solution that can help me on the internet.
Can you please help me?

Thank you

EDIT : I am on a emulator

Answer (score 0):

Check settings for "Application > Startup object". I had similar problem when startup object was missing.

Check this post [here](http://mbcdev.com/2014/01/06/error-failed-to-initialize-client-proxy-could-not-connect-to/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solution was to configurate the exakt same functions in the WMAppManifest.xml for both projects. After this it worked fine.